# Android: How to prevent opening physical keyboard restarting app

Tags: android, keyboard

I have my `android:screenOrientation="portait"` on but when a physical keyboard is opened it doesn't rotate the screen as I wanted, but it restarts the app. It seems to run onCreate over again or something. Can someone point me in the right direction and/or tell me how to intercept this and handle it? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Apart from `android:screenOrientation="portait"` try adding `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboard"`